# How to split a Python program into singel parts

Tags: python, function, module

I know there are many questions on global variables in functions, but I cannot find an answer to this:

I am currently writing a Python program for my RaspberryPi which receives messages from a Telegram-Bot, parses them and then executes certain functions (like switching on the coffeemachine, sending a Telegram message with information to myself, etc.).

To keep everything clear and neat, I would like to write some functions that do stuff like:

setting up initial variable values, empty strings, etc.
So that I can call e.g. set_up() and will be provided with this stuff.

Another function should for example "create the switches" (objects that are used to controll a 433MHz sender). The function could like this:

```
def create_switches():
plugCode=11010
Coffeemachine=pi_switch.RCSwitchA(plugCode, '10000')
Radio=pi_switch.RCSwitchA(plugCode, '01000')
Charger=pi_switch.RCSwitchA(plugCode, '00100')
```

and another function that gets the Telegram message as parameter and returns a result like:

```
todo = parse(telegramMessage)
```

which is then passed to:

```
execute(todo)
```

that calls functions like Coffemachine.switchOn(), based on the todo-parameter.

My only problem is that it won't work like that, because in "proper Python style" I need to return something at the end of the function so I can use it in the main program (as I did with todo=parse(...)).
But as I don't want to use functions because I need to do the same thing over and over again, but just because I want to keep the main script nice and clear and to be able to edit parts of the program without having to dive into the whole project's code, that doesn't really make things easier for me at all.

So do you have any suggestions how I can split my project in different parts and bring them together in the main script?

I only have experience with small Python scripts, that only do a few things at once and I'm able to write every single part of the program on its own, but I have no idea how to handle such "big" (for me) projects properly.

Thank you for any advice,

Franz

Comment: Read up on classes. They can be used to encapsulate related data and functions.

Comment: I know about classes.. I'm actually working with classes to handle the Telegram API.. but for the whole program what would be my objects/instances?

Comment: I think this question is too broad for Stack Overflow, because we can't really answer it without knowing a lot more about your specific program's goals. As general guidance though, read up on modules. [Here](http://intermediate-and-advanced-software-carpentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/structuring-python.html) is a pretty good discussion of modules and namespaces.

Comment: As an aside, I disagree with tdelaney's comment about classes - just because you need to encapsulate data and operations, it doesn't necessarily mean you should use classes - modules do this too. Your program seems fairly procedural, so a functional approach is probably still appropriate. Object-oriented programming and classes are awesome and powerful, but functional programming is still very relevant and Python supports it. Read up on both and choose the approach that is best for your task.